# How to get most prominent color in image Android

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I noticed Whatsapp Android has a feature where the `CollapsingToolbar` gets the most prominent color of the users' image and sets it as the toolbar color, I tried tranversing through an image and getting the most prominent color but the transversing was too slow, whatsApp does it in a blink, could someone who has done this before show me how to? and lastly how can I by default set my `CollapsingToolbar` to collapse when activity is just opened, I noticed by default it expands but I want it to collapse then if the user wish to, they can expand it by scrolling on it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for the strategy WhatsApp uses but the support library does offer `'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'` which can do just that for you.

```
Palette.generate(Bitmap toGetColorsFrom)
Palette.generate(Bitmap toGetColorsFrom, int maximumPaletteSize)
Palette.generateAsync(Bitmap toGetColorsFrom, PaletteAsyncListener listener)
Palette.generateAsync(Bitmap toGetColorsFrom, int maximumPaletteSize, PaletteAsyncListener listener)
```

The async methods require `Palette.PaletteAsyncListener` in order to notify you of the result.

Once you receive the `Palette` object from either of these methods you can set the toolbar backgroundColor like so:

```
Palette palette = Palette.generate(myBitmap);
Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(swatch.getRgb());
```

Note that `getVibrantSwatch()` is one way of getting a set of colors. You can also use:

```
Palette.getVibrantSwatch()
Palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch()
Palette.getLightVibrantSwatch()
Palette.getMutedSwatch()
Palette.getDarkMutedSwatch()
Palette.getLightMutedSwatch()
```

Answer (score 1):

For colors use [Palette library](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/extracting-colors-to-a-palette-with-android-lollipop/)

For setting your collapsing toolbar closed when the activity is opened you can set it by using in your activity.

`AppBarLayout layout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbarID);
 layout.setExpanded(false);//here appbarID is the id of your appbarlayout in your xml file containing collapsing toolbar`

hope it helps.

Comment: i do not have the `setExpanded` method in my collapingtoolbar

Comment: Call that method usong appbarlayout not collpasingtoolbar.

Comment: Ok maybe am cofusing thing, here is my code  
        mParent = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentCord);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
 how do I collapse collapingToolbar

Comment: I got it thanks, but its quit slow, I first see the image behind otherwise thanks.